# Cancel textbox from sending MouseLeave Messages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

Is there a way I can cancel the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message from a text box?

I have another control directly on top of it (I'm trying to get the Windows-drawn border). I'm manually invoking `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in the `MouseMove` event of that control to get the Aero blue border around the textbox to light up. Using Spy++, I see its firing `WM_MOUSELEAVE` even though I'm still in its bounds. That causes the blue border to disappear/reappear in a flicker.

*edit* I tried @Jeroen's answer and it reduces the flicker, but I still can't keep the glow on or it sticks too long.

```
        if (m.Msg == (int)Win32Api.WindowsMessages.MouseLeave)
        {
            var mousePosition = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            if (mousePosition.X < 0 || mousePosition.X > Width ||
                mousePosition.Y < 0 || mousePosition.Y > Height)
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
```

Comment: Did you hook into the messageloop (WndProc)?

Comment: Can you achieve the same effect if you set the focus of the control?

Comment: @Mehran - i already set the focus. this is when the user hovers over the text box, but does not focus it.

Comment: @Jeroen - how do i do that for textboxes?

Comment: I wish i could help you more but i don't understand how 2 controls on top of eachother and the windows-drawn border relate to eachother.

Comment: i'm trying to use the textbox's border but i have a link label on top of it.

Comment: Use the link label's Paint event to draw something that looks like a border with e.Graphics.DrawRectangle().

Comment: that's not what i want to do. i want to use the styling done for the textbox, not something custom.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for. It would require you to replace the `TextBox` definition with `tb` but maybe there's a more elegant way.

```
    public class tb : TextBox
            {

                private const int  WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;

                protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
                {
                    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSELEAVE)
                    {
                        // not passing the message on, so does nothing.
                        // handle it yourself here or leave empty.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // otherwise let windows handle the message
                        base.WndProc(ref m);
                    }
                }
            }
```